# Limit and complex numbers to infinity

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

The following sentence $$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} f(z) = 100i\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} f(1/z) = 100i.$$ Is this true?

Comment: It's not too clear to me what $z \to \infty$ means in this context. Does is mean the imaginary part of $z$ is 0 (or is fixed) and the real is infinite, or something else?

Comment: @gt6989b In complex analysis, the limit to infinity is often defined as, essentially, a limit with $|z| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally we have
$$
\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=l \iff \lim_{z\to\infty}f(1/z)=l.
$$
Suppose $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=l$. Then, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|z|<\delta \Longrightarrow  |l-f(z)|<\varepsilon.
$$
It follows that:
$$
|z|>\delta^{-1} \Longrightarrow |1/z|<\delta \Longrightarrow |l-f(1/z)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Hence $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(1/z)=l$.

Conversely, if we suppose that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(1/z)=l$, then given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $r>0$ such that
$$
|z|>r \Longrightarrow  |l-f(1/z)|<\varepsilon.
$$
It follows that
$$
|z|<r^{-1} \Longrightarrow |z^{-1}|=|1/z|>r \Longrightarrow |l-f(z)|=|l-f(1/z^{-1})|<\varepsilon,
$$
i.e. $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=l$.